# Как передать в другой метод переменную "var"?

Tags: c#

Метод_1 получает данные с сайта в переменную "var"

```
var resultRepo = await client_cur.Search.SearchRepo(request_repo);
```

В "var resultRepo" имеется коллекция объектов со свойствами.

Я планирую извлечь объекты и его свойства в "DataTable", а потом отобразит в "dataGridView" с использованием пагинации.
Для реализации выше изложенного предполагается использовать метод "Метод_2".

Вопрос.
Как передать "var resultRepo" в "Метод_2"?

Код используется отсюда - [link](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/blob/master/docs/search.md#search-repositories)

Предварительный код

```
public void method_1(string searchQuery_str)
    {
        // Поиск по "Репозитариям"            
        request_repo = new SearchRepositoriesRequest(searchQuery_str); // mvc client side framework - Структура клиентской стороны mvc           

        var resultRepo_1 = client_cur.Search.SearchRepo(request_repo);

       return resultRepo_1;
    }

    public void method_2(var resultRepo_1)
    {
        var resultRepo_2 = resultRepo_1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchQuery_str = textBox1.Text;
        method_1(searchQuery_str);            
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        method_2(resultRepo_1);
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84297/discussion-on-question-by-user9832524-------va).

Answer (score -1):

Навёл на переменную курсор.
Определил тип.
Тип - `SearchRepositoryResult`, библиотека `octokit.net`.

```
public void method_1(string searchQuery_str) 
            {
                // Поиск по "Реозитариям"            
                request_repo = new SearchRepositoriesRequest(searchQuery_str); // mvc client side framework - Структура клиентской стороны mvc           

                resultRepo_1 = client_cur.Search.SearchRepo(request_repo).Result;
            }

            public void method_2(SearchRepositoryResult resultRepo_1)
            {
                resultRepo_2 = resultRepo_1;
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string searchQuery_str = textBox1.Text;
                method_1(searchQuery_str);
            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                method_2(resultRepo_1);
            }
```